# SetState inside componentDidmount is throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am new to React JS and have started to create a small application in it. I'm facing some issue in `SetState` inside `componentDidmount` method.

I have a parent/home component, from where I would call a child component and pass an `Id` as a prop. Based on the id, an API call will be sent. After getting the required data from callback, I need to set the data retrieved it in the input box as value.

**Error:**

" A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. "

---

Code used:

**Child Component**:

```
import React from 'react';
class EditTodo extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
   super(props);

   this.onChangeTodoId = this.onChangeTodoId.bind(this);

   this.state={
    Todo_Id:''
   }
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/todo/'+this.props.match.params.id)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
        Todo_Id: data.Todo_Id
     })
    })
    .catch( (error)=>{
        console.log(error);
    })
}

onChangeTodoId(e){
    this.setState({
        Todo_Id: e.target.value
    });
}

render() { 
    return ( 
        <div>
            <form>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>ID: </label>
                            <input
                                    type="text" 
                                    className="form-control"
                                    value={this.state.Todo_Id}
                                    onChange={this.onChangeTodoId}
                                    />
                        </div> 
            </form>
        </div>
     );
}
}


export default EditTodo;
```

Comment: What is the type of data.Todo_Id?

Comment: Change the input box onChange code like this

Comment: onChange={() => this.onChangeTodoId()}

Comment: You should check whether `data.Todo_Id` is `undefined`. I think this error is likely to happen if the value of a text `input` changes to `undefined`.

Comment: I just executed the code, your setState function in onchange is working fine, you need to check the fetch method response in the componentDidMount function. May be the this.props.match.params.id is null or undefined while passing to the api

Comment: You'll get this warning if the variable used as the `input's` value is `null` or `undefined`. Based on the code you've provided that can only be caused by the `this.setState({Todo_Id: data.Todo_Id})`, make sure `data.Todo_Id` is not `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: You needed to bind the function or use ()=> Arrow function

Comment: @Titus, Thank you for you suggestion. Yes, the data.Todo_Id was undefined. After rendering the json properly (data[0].Todo_Id), It worked like a charm. Thank you... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React has 2 types of inputs: controlled or uncontrolled. controlled inputs receive a value trough the value attribute (more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html))

Your code seems fine but in this case your data.Todo_Id is likely undefined, which causes the error. Did you try to log the output of your api response?